grep does not return values from the dataframe
In the below code I am trying to select all the rows that starts with A from the data frame df_meth and df_exp. Both the df_meth and df_exp has over 65000 rows starting with A, B, C and D. A subset of df_meth and df_exp starting with A is shown below.
df_meth <- read.table('meth.tsv', header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
df_exp <- read.table('exp.tsv', header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
meth_A <- df_meth[, grep("^A", names(df_meth))]
exp_A <- df_exp[, grep("^A", names(df_exp))]

meth_A and exp_A are empty
> print(head(meth_A))
data frame with 0 columns and 6 rows
> print(head(exp_A))
data frame with 0 columns and 6 rows

> str(df_meth) 'data.frame': 65507 obs. of 2 variables: $ subgenome : chr "A" "A" "A" "A" ... $ Meth_value: num 0.9208 0.4727 0.1278 0.0253 0.0303 ..
    
df_meth:
subgenome Meth_value
A 0.920802534
A 0.472727273
A 0.127757353
A 0.025291829
A 0.030303030
A 0.165847666
A 0.072727273
A 0.001315789
A 0.446351931
A 0.415584416
A 0.846153846
A 0.013698630
A 0.095505618
A 0.195121951
A 0.102941176
A 0.150150150
A 0.450000000
A 0.025316456
A 0.646153846

df_exp:
subgenome TPM
A 0.000000
A 0.000000
A 25.687089
A 5.644342
A 20.459905
A 196.714492
A 4.629544
A 0.346602
A 90.000952
A 13.099918
A 0.329252
A 4.434103


can we please see str(df_meth)? The rownames of a data frame (if it has them) are rownames(df), not names(df); and you seem to be selecting columns rather than rows ... i.e. my guess is you want something like df_meth[grep("^A", rownames(df_meth)), ]


str(df_meth)
'data.frame': 65507 obs. of  2 variables:
$ subgenome : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
$ Meth_value: num  0.9208 0.4727 0.1278 0.0253 0.0303 ..


meth_B <- subset(df_meth, substr(subgenome, 1, 1) == "B")
exp_B <- subset(df_exp, substr(subgenome, 1, 1) == "B")

